# How to integrate the Html5 PhotoEditor sdk by img.ly with RubyonRails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, html, image-processing, sdk

I want to integrate my rails app with the free html5 PhotoEditorSDK by Img.ly. This should be quite simple as they have an understandable documentation about using their SDK. Please anybody should feel free to check them out. Here is their link. https://www.photoeditorsdk.com/documentation/html5/getting-started
Just looking for someone to point me in the right direction on how to integrate the SDK with my rails 4 app.

Comment: https://www.photoeditorsdk.com/documentation/html5/integration

Comment: @BradWerth  Read it, but where do i place those scipts in my rails app?